# Publish an angular web app with codeigniter Rest

Tags: mysql, rest, codeigniter, angular5, host

I have made a web app with angular 5 and a Codeigniter Rest (two separated folders) and now i want to put it on a free host to try it.
But someone told me to integrate my front part (angular) inside my back part (codeigniter). But i can't figure this out.

Does someone have some link for a tuto about this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can host your both backend and front end in apache server. Put the backend code in the home dir inside some other folder. For angular you can try the command from the root dir of angular from your local machine `ng build --prod` make sure to change the api urls in it to the hosted php url. Once the build is completed it will create a folder named `dist`. You can copy that into your websites public directory. Please keep in mind that once you made a change you have to take build again and upload it. I don't know any other ways exists for that. For the backend upload your db and change it's settings accordingly first. Make sure you are able to call the api.

Comment: So you say that i copy my back inside the Home folder of the angular project and execute a build command ?
And the new created folder will be put on the server ?
That's the basic Idea or am i wrong ?

Comment: @AlbanMartinez Yes you can copy the files in the generated dist folder into any public_html folder it will work.